# How to continue the method .animate instead of restarting it on mouse leave?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, carousel

I have this carousel. Mouseenter stop and mouseleave restart method .animate from the beggining. Any idea about how can I do to instead to restart the method on mouseleave finish it?

I mean, the method .animate go to marginLeft -124 now... So when you put the mouse on the animation stop.. to here cool, but if I release the mouse the animation start again from scratch but I want the animation keep going to the end...

"if I put the mouse on, the method will stop for example at margin left -60... so from here I want to continue to 0 instead to restart from -124 again"

I hope have been clear

Thanks in advance

```js
$(function() {
  var list = $('ul');
  var perro = $('.perro');
  
  function onAnimate() {  
    $('ul li:first-child').appendTo('ul');
    $('ul li:last-child').css('margin-Left', 0);
      
    move();
  }
  
  function move() {
    $('ul li:first-child')
        .animate({ marginLeft: -124  }, 1500, onAnimate);
  }
  
  list.find('li:even').addClass('even');
  list.find('li:odd').addClass('odd');
  
  list.on('mouseenter', 'li', function() {
    $('ul li:first-child').stop();
  });
  
  list.on('mouseleave', move);
  
  move();
});
```

```css
div { width:1080px;overflow:hidden; }
ul { list-style-type:none;width:10000px;margin:0;padding:0; }
li { height:400px;width:108px;float:left;text-align:center;margin:0;padding:0; }
.even {background: #ccc}
.odd {background: #4e4e4e;color:#fff;}

#tomas {
 width: 600px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<link href="carutomstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="carujava.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="new-carousel">
    <ul>
        <li class="perro">Item #1</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #2</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #3</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #4</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #5</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #6</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #7</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #8</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #9</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #10</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #11</li>
        <li class="perro">Item #12</li>
    </ul>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which carousel are you using?

Comment: the one you see here in the snippet

Answer (score 0):

I added new function called reset

```
list.on('mouseleave', reset);

function reset(){

     perro.each(function(e){
         list.append($('#item'+e, list));
     });

    move();

}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nnks19dc/1/)

Comment: thanks mate but is not working, after mouse leave happen some things really weirds... the idea is continue the .animate, no restart the function